# Is this really our new look?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, design

All I can say is... please, no.

[image]

It's like someone threw a bag of crayons at Windows 10.

The old 'fade out' version was fine. This is just a distraction.

For anyone who hasn't yet read the Meta post, this was what I was referring to - [New top bar is coming to the Stack Exchange network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/300829/new-top-bar-is-coming-to-the-stack-exchange-network?cb=1)

Comment: I bet this is related to the roll-out of the new topbar today on Meta Stack Exchange. It will be rolled out for moderators on all sites as well today (but it's not yet active). The old topbar had these bright colors as well, but only one or two pixels high. The new topbar is slightly higher, and they probably adjusted the 'underlay' upfront. But I agree with you, right now it's distracting.

Comment: It is distracting but still better than the new one. Text is more readable and usable than icons

Comment: After a few days ... I find I like it.

Comment: (I'm a Designer at Stack Exchange) small note: this bigger rainbow is just a *temporary* thing related to topbar update across network. it should be similar to @Glorfindel screenshot in answer below once it's launched to everyone.

Comment: @Paweł - phew.. good to know, thanks ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Thanks again for reporting. It should be fixed now.

Comment: It's been several days but I'm still seeing the rainbow.  It appears on the Ask Different main screen but not on the Ask Different Meta screen.  I'll give it another day and then I'll try Stylish for Safari and see if that helps.

Comment: @fsb rainbow was always there. the issue was about its height. also, rainbow was never visible on meta.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I never noticed it, strange.

Comment: Why does the rainbow no longer go all the way to the top of the screen behind the top bar? Was this an intentional change or just a side effect of fixing the taller rainbow?

Answer (score 6):

The new topbar has been rolled out today to Meta Stack Exchange, and a few moments ago to ♦ moderators on the entire network as well. This is how it looks like for me, and is going to look for you all as well (except for the diamond on the right):

[image]

You can see that the height of the bright rainbow has been reduced to a familiar level.

---

To disable the rainbow entirely, you can use a stylesheet manager, e.g. Stylish for Safari. Add the following rule for the domain `apple.stackexchange.com`:

```
body {
    background: none !important
}
```

[image]

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: It's much more subtle. I dig it.

Comment: I really don't like the rainbow of colors and wish there was a way to turn that off.  If anyone has a script (that an individual user can run) that would remove that bar, I would appreciate it.

Comment: @fsb there's a solution for that, please see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks @Glorfindel.  I use both Chrome and Safari (depending on which computer I'm on) so I'll look-up how to do this on Chrome.

Comment: To remove the rainbow whilst keeping the background the same colour instead of changing it to white, use `background: #f1f2f3 !important`. (cc @fsb)

Answer (score 3):

I've updated my stylesheet for a better top bar based on the Stack Overflow bar (which I released previously). This stylesheet rearranges the items to the correct order as they were previously, and also integrates the navigation into the top bar like Stack Overflow.

[image]

All this is achieved purely with CSS so there's no JavaScript overhead. You can find the latest version at https://georgegarside.com/blog/stack-exchange/better-top-nav-stack-overflow/